# Get filename from database and delete it from server

Tags: php, mysql, database, file-io, mysqli

I want to use PHP and MySQL to delete an image from a folder inside the server. The image name is inside the database (the format [jpg] is already included on the image name). I tried many ways and the following is one of them, but it's not working yet. Help please.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit2'])) {
    $numeroimagem = $_POST["numero"];

    $imagem=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT imagem FROM galeria WHERE numero='$numeroimagem'");
    $nomeimagem=mysqli_fetch_row ($imagem);

    $target = '../imgs/galeria/'.$nomeimagem;

    if (file_exists($target)) {
        unlink($target);
    }
}
```

The form:

```
<form action="" method="post">
   <input name="numero" type="text" size="3" maxlength="3"><input type="submit" name="submit2" value="Delete"><br>
</form>
```

Comment: your code only verify if image file exists... post the error

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not just save the hassle and store the image(s) as BLOB?

Comment: @高科技黑手 The database would get "heavier" I didn't want that for the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out the problem. I was getting Array on the file name it was solved by adding [0] like this:

```
$target = '../imgs/galeria/'.$nomeimagem[0];
```

Thanks for the tips anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to delete the file. You can use the function unlink for that:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php

Comment: I forgot to paste that here but I have unlink on my code and still does not work... I'm editing the question now.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot know exactly the error, but the main issue was the File what not with realpath function.

Realpath function resolves if a path is correcty

if you try realpath('../imgs/galeria/') php will resolve full path.

If realpath return false or null, the path cannot be resolved, when you have to try accoplish the right path.

If you are running script from folder scripts/delete-imagem.php, and the files at public/imgs/galeria, you should use realpath('../public/images/) to get full path.

Once you get the full path, you should try to remove it using "unlink()"

```
$path = realpath('../public/imgs/galeria/');
if(is_dir($path)) {
    if(is_file($path.'/'.$fileName)) { //Note that realpath trim the final "/" from filepath.
         unlink($path.'/'.$fileName);
    {
}
```

This code will force it works.

Comment: I tried realpath('../imgs/galeria/') and still is not working :(